# Trying to put the data from wide to long with multiple variables that are each different R

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot

I am trying to use pivot_longer to move my data from wide to long in R. However, I have multiple different variable that will need to be created. I want to create a column called "Assessment" that has "pre" or "post" within it. Then I want a column that says "Test" with "A or B" in it, then I want a "Error" column with the values for only the columns that currently say "error" and then a "Time" column for the values for only the columns that currently say "time" in them. Right now the data looks like this:

```
data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
      Testing.Date = c("5/25/23","5/30/23","5/31/23",
                       "6/1/23","6/27/23","6/20/23"),
                ID = c(101L, 103L, 106L, 109L, 110L, 201L),
         Condition = c("Lab", "Nature", "Nature", "Lab", "Nature", "Lab"),
               Age = c(21L, 22L, 22L, 21L, 29L, 56L),
        Pre.Time.A = c(22.78, 15.75, 30.33, 18.43, 26.99, 24.94),
       Pre.Error.A = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
        Pre.Time.B = c(60.38, 61.65, 65.6, 65.73, 58.63, 60.97),
     Pre.Error.B = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L),
       Post.Time.A = c(21.48, 14.65, 20.66, 24.55, 23.87, 35.7),
      Post.Error.A = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
       Post.Time.B = c(45.88, 48.58, 56.45, 48.95, 53, 64.3),
      Post.Error.B = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)
)
```

I want it to look like this:

```
TMT_long <- tibble::tribble(
              ~Testing.Date,  ~ID, ~Condition, ~Age, ~Assessment, ~Test, ~Time, ~Errors,
                  "5/25/23", 101L,      "Lab",  21L,       "Pre",   "A", 22.78,      0L,
                  "5/25/23", 101L,      "Lab",  21L,       "Pre",   "B", 60.38,      0L,
                  "5/25/23", 101L,      "Lab",  21L,      "Post",   "A", 21.48,      0L,
                  "5/25/23", 101L,      "Lab",  21L,      "Post",   "B", 45.88,      0L
              )
```

I can't seem to figure out the right syntax in `pivot_longer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the values to be manipulated are numeric, it's simple to combine them and then pivot them wider again:

`separate` splits the `name` column into new variables, by default on non-alphanumeric values, so using the `.` in the values. You could specify it with `separate(., sep = "[.]")`.

```
df_wide <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("P")) %>%
  separate(name, into = c("Assessment", "time_err", "Test")) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = time_err)
```

Produces:

```
head(df_wide)

  Testing.Date    ID Condition   Age Assessment Test   Time Error
  <chr>        <int> <chr>     <int> <chr>      <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 5/25/23        101 Lab          21 Pre        A      22.8     0
2 5/25/23        101 Lab          21 Pre        B      60.4     0
3 5/25/23        101 Lab          21 Post       A      21.5     0
4 5/25/23        101 Lab          21 Post       B      45.9     0
5 5/30/23        103 Nature       22 Pre        A      15.8     0
6 5/30/23        103 Nature       22 Pre        B      61.6     0
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be better to be more specific than `starts_with(p)`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    matches(r'(error|time)')
  ) %>% 
  separate_wider_delim(
    cols = name,
    delim = '.',
    names = c('Assessment', 'Type', 'Test')
  ) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = 'Type',
    values_from = 'value'
  )
#> # A tibble: 24 x 8
#>    Testing.Date    ID Condition   Age Assessment Test   Time Error
#>    <chr>        <int> <chr>     <int> <chr>      <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 5/25/23        101 Lab          21 Pre        A      22.8     0
#>  2 5/25/23        101 Lab          21 Pre        B      60.4     0
#>  3 5/25/23        101 Lab          21 Post       A      21.5     0
#>  4 5/25/23        101 Lab          21 Post       B      45.9     0
#>  5 5/30/23        103 Nature       22 Pre        A      15.8     0
#>  6 5/30/23        103 Nature       22 Pre        B      61.6     0
#>  7 5/30/23        103 Nature       22 Post       A      14.6     0
#>  8 5/30/23        103 Nature       22 Post       B      48.6     0
#>  9 5/31/23        106 Nature       22 Pre        A      30.3     1
#> 10 5/31/23        106 Nature       22 Pre        B      65.6     1
#> # i 14 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner:

```
tidyr::pivot_longer(df, matches("P"), names_pattern = "(.*)\\.(.*)\\.(.*)", names_to = c("Assessment", ".value", "Test"), values_drop_na = TRUE)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 24 × 8
   Testing.Date    ID Condition   Age Assessment Test   Time Error
   <chr>        <int> <chr>     <int> <chr>      <chr> <dbl> <int>
 1 5/25/23        101 Lab          21 Pre        A      22.8     0
 2 5/25/23        101 Lab          21 Pre        B      60.4     0
 3 5/25/23        101 Lab          21 Post       A      21.5     0
 4 5/25/23        101 Lab          21 Post       B      45.9     0
 5 5/30/23        103 Nature       22 Pre        A      15.8     0
 6 5/30/23        103 Nature       22 Pre        B      61.6     0
 7 5/30/23        103 Nature       22 Post       A      14.6     0
 8 5/30/23        103 Nature       22 Post       B      48.6     0
 9 5/31/23        106 Nature       22 Pre        A      30.3     1
10 5/31/23        106 Nature       22 Pre        B      65.6     1
# ℹ 14 more rows
```

Notes:

- thanks to Josh for the `matches()` idea, I hadn't seen that before
- `names_pattern` essentially matches the column names as a regex, turning the prefix and suffix values into values in the Assessment and Test columns respectively, and the central part into the values of the time and error columns

Comment: You could also use `names_sep = '[.]'` instead of `names_pattern` for those who do not know regex